# ValueError: The provided validation time series dataset is too short for obtaining even one training point

Tags: python, machine-learning

Working on the darts' temporal convolution n/w.

```
model_TCN = TCNModel(
        input_chunk_length=65,
        output_chunk_length=52, 
        n_epochs=EPOCH,
        dropout=DROP,
        dilation_base=2,
        weight_norm=True,
        batch_size=16,
        kernel_size=5,
        num_filters=3,
        optimizer_kwargs={'lr': LEARN},
        # log_tensorboard=True,
        # force_reset=True,
        random_state=42)

model_TCN.fit(series=train,
                val_series=val,
                verbose=True)

train = ts_darts[:248]
val = ts_darts[248:295]
```

Getting the below error while trying to fit the model.

```
ValueError: The provided validation time series dataset is too short for obtaining even one training point.
```

Comment: your input_chunk_length is 65. You validation dataset is smaller than that. 

two solutions:

1. increase the size of the validation dataset
2. decrease the input_chunk_length to a reasonable size.